# spring maven profile - set properties file based on compilation profile

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, spring-profiles, maven-profiles, spring-properties

I would create some compilation profiles like these:

- profile name: dev
- profile name: test
- profile name: production

In src/main/resources I have 3 folders:

- dev/file.properties
- test/file.properties
- production/file.properties

Each file contains different values for this properties:

```
- my.prop.one
- my.prop.two
- my.prop.three
```

After that I would set in Spring classes something like these:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("file:${profile_name}/file.properties")
public class MyConfig{

}
```

How can I do?

Comment: Using a variable that depends on your build environment in production code is not a clean solution. What's the difference between `dev` tests and `test` tests? If you can reduce this to `test` and `production` you can place one `file.properties` in `/src/main/resources` and one in `/src/test/resources` and Maven will handle their packaging automagically.

Comment: No, I have 3 environment. How can I do=

Comment: Do the three `file.properties` just differ in configuration values in identical configuration lines or do they contain different configuration lines too?

Comment: They only contain different values for the properties.

Comment: Fine. That makes it easier. See my answer.

Comment: hi! have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See  [Apache Maven Resources Plugin / Filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) and [Maven: The Complete Reference - 9.3. Resource Filtering](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-description.html). (*Filtering* is a bad name, IMHO, since a filter usually filters something *out*, while we perform *string interpolation* here. But that's how it is.)

Create *one* `file.properties` in `src/main/resources` that contains `${...}` variables for the values that should change according to your environment.

Declare default properties (those for `dev`) and activate resource filtering in your POM:

```
<project>
  ...
  <properties>
    <!-- dev environment properties, 
         for test and prod environment properties see <profiles> below -->
    <name>dev-value</name>
    ...
  </properties>

  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
  </build>
  ...
```

Declare two profiles with the according properties in your POM:

```
  ...  
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>test</id>
      <properties>
        <name>test-value</name>
        ...
      </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>prod</id>
      <properties>
        <name>prod-value</name>
        ...
      </properties>
    </profile>

  </profiles>
  ...
```

Use in your code just:

```
@PropertySource("file:file.properties")
```

Activate the profiles with:

```
mvn ... -P test ...
```

or

```
mvn ... -P prod ...
```

Comment: With this solution properties values are hard coded in pom? I am not sure that I have understand.

Comment: @michele Have you looked at the example in the second link I supplied? That basically describes exactly what you're looking for: "_If you need to use a different [x] in development and a different [x] in production._" And it's done there in the same way I described for your demand here.

Comment: @michele "Hardcoded" is the wrong word here. The values have to be defined somewhere in the end. Now think what's a better, a cleaner solution: Having _three_ files which just differ in configuration values (remember DRY), which _all_ contain "hardcoded" values _and_ a build time dependency in production code we don't know how to resolve yet _or_ having just one file that's dynamically updated with values from where they belong to: the build configuration (the title of your question contains "_based on compilation profile_").